# bash netcat proxy combined with awk

Tags: bash, proxy, awk, netcat

In cygwin, I am trying to setup a netcat proxy, as follows:

1. **The server**: in one terminal I am running

   ```
   nc -lp 6000
   ```
2. **The proxy**: in a second terminal I am running the proxy (listening on 2000 and passing farther to 6000).
3. **The client**: in a third terminal I am running

   ```
   nc localhost 2000
   ```

#### The test

Typing something in *client* should show up on *server*. Typing something in *server*, should show up on *client*.

Below is what I tried to do in the 2nd terminal:

1. This one works fine:

   ```
   nc -lp 2000 <fifo | tee /dev/stderr | nc localhost 6000 >fifo
   ```

*(where fifo was previously setup with "mkfifo fifo")*

1. But... these do not work :(

   ```
   nc -lp 2000 <fifo | awk '{print}' | nc localhost 6000 >fifo
   nc -lp 2000 <fifo | awk -f my.awk | nc localhost 6000 >fifo
   nc -lp 2000 <fifo | awk -f my.awk - | nc localhost 6000 >fifo
   ```

*(where my.awk contains just {print})*

Please helppppppppppppppp!!!!!!!!
Thanks in advance,
Adrian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to buffering and there is no standard way to turn it off in awk.  On some systems you can hack around it by calling `fflush`, for example:

```sh
nc -lp 2000 <fifo | awk '{print}{fflush()}' | nc localhost 6000 >fifo
```

Sadly this doesn't always work depending on platform and awk version.  You might consider using a different processor that allows you to disable buffering, such as Perl.